# Yahoo PHP SDK - consumer key rejected error

Tags: yahoo

I am trying to use the PHP SDK provided by Yahoo on my website.
I have not requested any extra private data (special permissions).

However, I keep getting the error `oauth_problem=consumer_key_rejected` every time I try.

Can someone please tell me what could be the mistake I'm making?

Please do let me know if you need further info on the same.

Comment: This is an old question, but if you still need help on it, please provide more details about how you are using the PHP SDK, including any code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It seems unrelated, but once I enabled permission for private data access, the problem went away. I believe you can pick any private data access. For example, I enabled "Knowledge Plus" and it's now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should create account in Yahoo! Messenger OAuth API Key.
Then you will receive Keys. 
and Yahoo Messenger API for php has some problem,but the base works correctly.

for example it will make JSON code by hand:D

```
{'':''}
```

something like it,but you should make it by `json_encode()` php function.